# Python file contents to dictionary with empty lines

Tags: python

Hi Friends I have file like below format

```
#temp.txt

fruit apple
vegi  leafy
```

I'm trying to read file and push elements into dictionary using below code

```
with open("temp.txt") as fd:
    d = dict(line.rstrip().split(None, 1) for line in fd)
```

Say if my input file has new empty line at the end of file I get following error

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #2 has length 0; 2 is required
```

Can someone let me know how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("temp.txt") as fd:
    d = dict(line.rstrip().split(None, 1) for line in fd if not line == '\n')
```

Comment: @Bhaskarvedula Do click on the tick mark below the answer's score if this has answered your question ;) Otherwise, your question will stay listed as unanswered in the questions list.

Comment: I'm new to Stackoverflow. Thanks for guiding :-)

Answer (score 0):

As your `temp.txt` files has empty lines in it, it will fail when you try an strip and split the line and it does not result in two arguments.

Although not as elegant, you might need to test you have two arguments on each line, otherwise it will also fail if one of your lines has just a single argument. For example you could do the following:

```
with open("temp.txt") as fd:
    d = dict(line.rstrip().split(None, 1) for line in fd if len(line.rstrip().split(None, 1)) == 2)
```

This would then work with a file such as the following, where it would ignore the second `fruit` entry:

```
fruit apple

vegi  leafy
fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to do inside the `with`:

```
try:
    -your statement-
except ValueError:
    continue
```

Comment: Note: You would need to use a normal for loop for this to work, rather than a list comprehension.

Comment: Oh, you mean, this would output no dictionary at all if there is an error?
Sorry, I didn't test it, since I didn't have the file; ... I thought, the `with` works like a loop, but it probably doesn't at all

Comment: For a list comprehension it would probably give you a syntax error, as the `continue` would not be inside the `for`